# How to obtain MAX value and its column header from only 1 row in a table?

Tags: mysql

Basically I have a sample table:

```
Town          V1     V2      V3      V4      V5
New York    0.12    0.1    0.11     0.21    -0.12
```

From a sample query:

```
SELECT town, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5 FROM sample
```

I would like a query to return just the following:

```
New York V4 0.21
```

Which means, I would like to return town, header of the max value (V4) and max value (0.21)

Is there any easy way of doing it in MySQL?

Comment: `SELECT GREATEST(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5)` will return the greatest value.  Not sure how to get the header to return with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no `NULL` values, then:

```
select town, greatest(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5)
```

This is more painful if you do have `NULL` values.  If you know the values are never negative:

```
select town,
       nullif(greatest(coalesce(v1, -1), coalesce(v2, -1), coalesce(v3, -1),
                       coalesce(v4, -1), coalesce(v5, -1)), -1)
```